# Visual Representation of an HTML table getting changed after inserting php code inside <td> tag

Tags: php, html, scripting

I am not getting the proper representation of an HTML table after inserting php code in
"td" tag while the code is is php page only so that server can execute the code inside the "td" tag. Following is the code  :

```
<table border=1>
<tr>

    <td><select name="designer_response" id="designer_response" <?php if($variable == 0)echo 'disabled=disabled' ?> ><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select></td>
    <td><textarea name="designer_comments" id="designer_comments"><?php echo "".$designer_c ?></textarea></td>
    <td><select name="reviewer_response" id="reviewer_response"><option value="Yes">Yes</option value="No"><option>No</option></select></td>
    <td><textarea name="reviewer_comments" id="reviewer_comments"><?php echo "".$reviewer_c ?></textarea></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks...

Please find the php code that modifies and defines the variables in the code snppet given above :

```
<?php
$id = 'Q420';
$phase_of_review = 0;
$designereviewer_r = "";
$designereviewer_c = "";
$reviewer_r = "";
$reviewer_c = "";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("checklist", $con);

//Extracting data...
$s = "select * from dummy";
$resource = mysql_query($s , $con);
if($resource == TRUE)
{

//Yes data is there , fetch it ..
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
$designer_r = $data['designer_response'];
$designer_c = $data['designer_comments'];
$reviewer_r = $data['reviewer_response'];
$reviewer_c = $data['reviewer_comments'];

echo "designer_response".$designer_r;
 }

  else
  $phase_of_review = 1; 

  $variable = 1;
 ?>
```

Below is the output html of the php code given above:

```
<table border=1 bordercolor="black">

<tr>
<td><select name="designer_response" id="designer_response"       ><optionvalue="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select></td>
<td><textarea name="designer_comments" id="designer_comments">ok2</textarea></td>
<td><select name="reviewer_response"   id="reviewer_response"><option  value="Yes">Yes</option value="No"><option>No</option></select></td>
<td><textarea name="reviewer_comments" id="reviewer_comments">ok3</textarea></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: What *are* you getting? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Please post the PHP code, including the part that sets the variables involed, and describe what you think is wrong in the presentation. Also run HTML validation, as your code now has a syntax error.

Comment: @ Jukka K. Korpela Hi Jukka , Added the code..

Comment: @Quentin Hi Quentin , Before the table an unknown input field is being created...while the formatting of a statement before the first row in table is also changing after adding the php code in &lt;td&gt; tag

Comment: Can you post the output HTML from your PHP?  That will help us see what you're actually getting to determine where things might be off a bit.

Comment: @TLS added the html produced from php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things stand out to me in the output HTML, but I'm not sure they will actually solve your problems.  First, there is a space missing with the first "Yes" option tag in the output HTML, but this could be just a copy/paste issue.  In the output HTML, the first option tag is appearing as `optionvalue`, which is invalid.

Second, you have the `value="No"` attribute in your `reviewer_response` select list in the closing `option` tag for the "Yes" option rather than in the opening tag of the "No" option.

To me, neither of those really says, "this is what's causing the primary issue;" however, cleaning up the little issues with the code could solve the bigger problems as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks @TLS for pointing out , the wrong marking in <option> tag was creating problem..